# Dropzone.js - Does this support screen clip pasting?

Tags: dropzone

I want to create an app that is similar to drag & drop, but instead, I want to paste screen clips/screenshots and pass that image to the server for additional image-to-text processing. Does dropzone.js support this and if it does, how so?